# Initiate SRAM read operation

Tags: c, embedded, arm

I am programming an ARM chip (STM32F2) "bare-metal". Specifically, I would like to read values held in external SRAM. Reading the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00225773.pdf) I understand that such memory transactions are done through the FSMC (Flexible Static Memory Controller).

I understand how to initialise the FSMC for SRAM read/write operations. (I have to set the appropriate GPIO pins to the correct Alternate Function, modify a bunch of control registers, etc.). However, I do not see how to initiate, for example, a read operation.

What registers should I touch to read (or write) the SRAM after initialisation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I've understood it, you get "memory-mapped" access through the FSMC controller. So  all you need to do is decide in what address space to map the SRAM, and then just access it through pointers initialized to point there.

Comment: Ah, well that sounds easy! Thanks.

Comment: @Randomblue: It is easy, and further, if you add the SRAM region to your link map, the compiler will use it automatically for static memory or you may locate your heap there.  You should in this case initialise the SRAM in the runtme start-up, and if doing it in C code, (or if any C code runs before external RAM is initialised) make sure that the stack is not mapped to the external memory.

Comment: @Clifford: Thanks. How can I add the SRAM region to my link map? I've never really touched a linker script before. What lines should I write?

Comment: @unwind: Does the same procedure hold for *write* operations? I can now read the SRAM, but not write on it.

Comment: @Randomblue: That would depend on what tool chain you are using. Whether I can answer your question may also depend on what you are using.  Regarding read/write,  if you can't write it, how do you know you are reading it?  What you are reading is more likley not SRAM content - unless you have a hardware fault.   The processor will allow you to read any valid address - even if there is nothing mapped to it. Configuring the FSMC, GPIO and clocks is quite involved on STM32 and easy to get wrong.